# How to bulk copy one field to a first object of array and update the document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bulkupdate

I want to copy price information in my document to `prices[]` array.

```
var entitiesCol = db.getCollection('entities');
entitiesCol.find({"type": "item"}).forEach(function(item){
    item.prices = [ {
        "value": item.price
    }];
    entitiesCol.save(item);
});
```

It takes too long time and some fields are not updated.

I am using Mongoose in server side and I can also use it.

What can I do for that?

Comment: What is your Mongoose and MongoDB version?

Comment: MongoDB 3.2.11 I guess

Answer (score 1):

In the mongo shell, you can use the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** method to carry out the updates in a fast and efficient manner. Consider the following example:

```
var entitiesCol = db.getCollection('entities'),
    counter = 0,
    ops = [];
entitiesCol.find({
    "type": "item",
    "prices.0": { "$exists": false }
}).snapshot().forEach(function(item){
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": item._id },
            "update": { 
                "$push": {
                    "prices": { "value": item.price }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    counter++;

    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        entitiesCol.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (counter % 500 !== 0) 
    entitiesCol.bulkWrite(ops);
```

The `counter` variable above is there to manage your bulk updates effectively if your collection is large. It allows you to batch the update operations and sends the writes to the server in batches of 500 which gives you a better performance as you are not sending every request to the server, just once in every 500 requests.

For bulk operations MongoDB imposes a [default internal limit of 1000](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) operations per batch and so the choice of 500 documents is good in the sense that you have some control over the batch size rather than let MongoDB impose the default, i.e. for larger operations in the magnitude of > 1000 documents.

Comment: Should I use snapshot() ?

Comment: @Burak Yes indeed, as long as it is with unsharded collections and bear in mind that `snapshot()` does not guarantee isolation from insertion or deletions.

Comment: What if I don't want to push into prices array? I just want to set it. Because if I run this for second time, array will have duplicate price

Comment: Does the `prices` array exist prior to the update? If not then `$push` will create it otherwise you would need to use the `$set` operator.

Comment: You could check for its existence first in the query, considering that you have some documents which were updated before or use the `$addToSet` operator which adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case `$addToSet` does nothing to that array.